# Android Add alphbetical order to child in EpandableListView

Tags: android, baseadapter, expandablelistadapter

I know how to do an alphabetical order on a ListView in my BaseAdaptor, in the getView methode, i do something like that . How to do the same thing for an expandable list view ? >>>>

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if((position==0)||position>0&&mValues[position].charAt(0)!= mValues[position-1].charAt(0))

    {
        //Instanciation de notre separateur et qui a pour valeur la premiere lettre de l'élément courant

        View v = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
        TextView separator = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.separator);
        separator.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        separator.setText(mValues[position].substring(0,1));

        // Intanciation de l'élément courant

        TextView name= (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.name);
        name.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        name.setText(mValues[position]);

        return v;

    }
    else
    {

    View v = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
    TextView name= (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.name);
    name.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    name.setText(mValues[position]);

    return v;

    }

}
```

Comment: Do the same in getChildView()

Comment: @AlexGoncalves You've asked 10 questions, 9 of them have answers, and you accepted only one answer. Fix your accept ratio, dude.

Comment: Sorry I didn't know how that work...